# RxJS: making a buffer emit after certain event

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Problem: I would like to create Rxjs composition ( function chain ) that would result in buffering values from one Observable until certain event occurs then emmiting all buffered values synchroniously and then buffering until next event.

I use this function to gather all http requests that have to wait until my application make a call for authorization. And then run all those requests. ( Its implemented inside Angular4 HttpClient Interceptor ), thats my usecase but I generally seek solution on how to create such rx chain.

Why Rxjs buffer is not enoyugh. From what I read and tested buffer either requires exact time frames, or in case of getting a scheduler instead of time as parameter, its resubscribes to scheduler after detecting last scheduler`s "event" propagation. And I would like it work like this: When there appears first request I start to buffer and then subscribe to scheduler, after scheduler emits, a stop buffering, reemit all buffered values, and wait until next new request is made to start buffering again and to launch scheduler again.

Right now my solution is using helper object thats either undefined or my observable, with code roughly as follows:

```
private observable: Observable<boolean>;

makeRequest(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.observable !== void 0) {
        return this.observable;
    } else {
        this.observable = this.authenticationReuqest()
            .share()
            .finally(() => this.observable = void 0);

        return this.observable;
    }
}
```

In that way I kind of buffer my requests, by maiking them .delay() until same multicasted observable emits, and after it emits I just clean it up (though no need for unsubscribing as its cleans up on finally so after completing or erroring).

If anyone has an idea or patter how to replace this solution with pure Rxjs I am intrested. I have some feeling that some combination of Buffer and Zip could make it happen though I cant get the exact solution.

Thanks
Tomasz

Comment: The `buffer()` operator doesn't resubscribe to its notifier. I think what you describe here is exactly how the `buffer` operator works right now.

Comment: @martin as stated in documentation http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html buffer when takes some parameter describing time window (either time or another observable)  have timeframes appear one after another.
My second observable is Http request. I want to buffer while waiting for this request. I want to send that request when I get first unbuffered value and buffer values until this http request end.

Comment: What I believe buffer allows to do is to have an timeframe defined by Observable, but it does not allow any interaction between buffered source and this timeframe providing observable.
If you have exact example on how to simply implement it using just buffer functionality I would be more than happy to see it.

Comment: This article explains how to do exactly what you're describing https://alligator.io/rxjs/buffering-operators/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into exactly the same problem, I have events coming in like this

[image]

I kick off loading events early so that we don't need to wait. But the problem is, only after one point (the "rdy", stands for ready) I want to process these events. So the ready event needs to come first. I need to hold the values until ready comes and reemit them. Like this

[image]

Here's what I do, I use `multicast` to share the same subscription in downstream. Create a ready observable in the selector function filtering the first ready event. Then merge the ready observable, and buffer of the multicasted events, take one, and switchMap back from array to values. Finally concat the multicasted events. Here's the code

```
const events = [
  'ev1',
  'ev2',
  'ready',
  'ev3',
  'ev4',
  'ev5'
]
Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .take(events.length)
  .map(i => events[i])
  .multicast(
      () => new Rx.Subject(),
      events$ => {
          const ready$ = events$
            .filter(event => event === 'ready')
            .take(1)
          return Rx.Observable
            .merge(
                ready$,
                events$
                  .buffer(ready$)
                  .take(1)
                  .switchMap(events => Rx.Observable.from(events))
            )
                .concat(events$)
      }
  )
```

Or you can find it and run it on RxViz here https://rxviz.com/v/j8nNpe8N
It's not pretty, but it works. I am still looking for a better way to do it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [bufferWhen](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#bufferwhen): it buffers value from an observable until a second one emits.

Comment: Unfortunatelly bufferWhen can not, out of the box, resubscribe to second observable after getting new (unbuffered) request,

I would have to set arbitrary time after which I resubscribe to the second one, or resubscribe immediately after it finishes previous call. I look for a lazy pattern, to call the second one only onec per buffer and only when needed not in set periods of time.

Comment: @TomaszStelągowski Aha, thanks a lot, that helps me understand why `bufferWhen()` wasn't working for me!

Answer (score 0):

I also spent time looking into this exact issue, and I couldn't figure it out. In the end, I got the following to work. I feel confident there must be a more idiomatic / elegant approach, but I am able to understand this approach as a new RxJS user.

```typescript
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { tap, scan, filter, map } from "rxjs/operators";

const clicks = fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
  scan(acc => acc + 1, 0),
  tap((v) => console.log("tapping", v))
);

const out = clicks.pipe(
  // tap(v => console.log('before scan', v)),
  scan((acc, count) => {
    if (count % 3 === 0) {
      return {acc: [], out: acc.acc.concat(count)}
    }
    return {out: [], acc: acc.acc.concat(count)}
  }, {acc: [] as number[], out: [] as number[]}),
  // tap(v => console.log('after scan', v)),
  filter(obj => obj.out.length > 0),
  map(obj => obj.out)
)

out.subscribe(v => console.log('out', v))
```

The key is that I used `scan()` as a running reducer and then filter out values. I build my own "buffer" of values from each subsequent value in the `.scan()` and then remove any events which don't have the "ready" state in the next filter.

Seems ugly, but allows for my use case which is a bit more complex than ready events. I'm parsing `git-remote-helper` commands, some which end with a double newline and some which don't.